# How to use an iMac G3 as an external monitor?

Tags: display, external-display, computer-building, imac, crt

I've read that the tray-loading iMac G3's CRT display is connected to the circuit board with a simple plug. Can I unplug the CRT from the computer part and use the iMac G3 as an external monitor? How can I do this? I couldn't find any good tutorials on YouTube or anywhere else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Can I unplug the CRT from the computer part and use the iMac G3 as an external monitor?"* -- Highly unlikely.  The standard PC video interface is VGA/VESA, and Apple has no incentive to adhere to a Wintel PC interface.  There's probably an internal RGB interface for which you have no electrical and timing specifications.  If there's a serial port, then you could turn it into a VDT, video display terminal.

Comment: @sawdust There is an internal DB-15 connector that plugs into the card.